# Can't update a variable with multiple methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to build a small game that transitions between levels when you finish the previous one.

```
// The game starts at level 1.
public int levelCounter = 1;

//When levelComplete() executes it should increase the counter by 1.
public int levelComplete()
{

    if ( testLevelComplete() )
    {
        showWarning("Level Complete!");
        levelCounter += 1;

        return levelCounter;
    }
    else
    {
        return levelCounter;
    }
}

//This method should check levelCounter for the level number and load the 
//appropriate level.
public void levelChange()
{

    if( levelCounter == 2 )
    {
        setLevel(level2, 2);
    }
    else if( levelCounter == 3 )
    {
        setLevel(level3, 3);
    }

}
```

My code works to generate level 2, but after that when i finish level 2 it just reloads level 2 and i can't seem to increase the counter past 2.

My code is all being executed in a loop

EDIT: sorry guys, first time poster, wasnt really sure how to properly present my problem

my testLevelComplete() method works perfectly, it gives me the warning box when i finish my levels. i think the problem lies within the scope,  between the two methods and my variable.

```
 private final char[][] level1 = {
    {'#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '.', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', ' ', '$', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}
};

private final char[][] level2 = {
    {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', '@', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '$', '$', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#'},
    {'#', ' ', '$', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', '.', '#'},
    {'#', '#', '#', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'},
    {' ', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '.', '#'},
    {' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', '#'},
    {' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', '#', '#', '#'},
    {' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' ', ' ', ' '},
};

private final char[][] level3 = {
    {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '#', '@', ' ', '#', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '$', '*', ' ', '#', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', '.', '*', ' ', '#', ' '},
    {'#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' '},
    {'#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', ' '},
};

//This executes repeatedly
public void act() 
{

    direction();

    levelComplete();

    levelChange();


}


public void setLevel(char[][] level, int levelNum)
{
    ClaraWorld nextLevel = new ClaraWorld(level, levelNum);
    Greenfoot.setWorld(nextLevel);
}

public int levelCounter = 1;

public void levelChange()
{

    if( levelCounter == 2 )
    {
        setLevel(level2, 2);
    }
    else if( levelCounter == 3 )
    {
        setLevel(level3, 3);
    }

}

public int levelComplete()
{

    if ( testLevelComplete() )
    {
        showWarning("Level Complete!");
        levelCounter += 1;

        return levelCounter;
    }
    else
    {
        return levelCounter;
    }

}
```

the direction() method works fine, it just controls my character

Comment: The behavior suggests that `testLevelComplete()` returns false after the first level so that you never increment the `levelCounter` again.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `levelComplete()` when you complete a level. In that case, if the level doesn't increase it means your `testLevelComplete()` method is returning false. Are you seeing the `Level complete!` warning anywhere? edit your question and add its' code if that's case and you can't figure out why it's returning `false`

Comment: What does `testLevelComplete()` do?

Comment: Can you supply a minimum working example of your code? As it stands, it is impossible to answer as there is no interaction between the two methods you've presented and the other methods you call are not shown.

Comment: post all your related code

Comment: what does setLevel(int, int) do ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should also reconsider your "architect". Why don't you store your levels in an array or a map? then it would look something like this:

```
    // declaration
    private int currentLevel = 0;
    private List<Level> levels = new ArrayList<Level>();

    // constructor
    levels.add(new Level(level1));
    levels.add(new Level(level2));
    levels.add(new Level(level3));
    levels.add(new Level(level4));

    //methods

    // test if level is completed
    public boolean levelComplete()
    {
        if ( testLevelComplete()){
            showWarning("Level Complete!");
            currentLevel++;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // change current level
    public void levelChange(){
        setLevel(levels.get(currentLevel), currentLevel);
    }
```